# Movement Along Locked Axis With Limit Distance Constraint?

Tags: constraints

There is a sphere with only **X axis** free for location, both **Y** and **Z** are locked. So movement is possible only along x axis.

Now if I add a **Limit Distance** constraint to this sphere with a target that's situated below it and try to move the sphere by pressing **G** and moving the mouse, the sphere actually moves in Z direction.

How can an object move along an axis which is locked?

[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer but if you give it 2 constraints, Limit Distance and Limit Location at the bottom, it will work as you expect

Comment: Locking an axis only restricts you from changing that value with 3D viewport manipulations.  It does nothing else.  Everything else still acts on it, ranging from manually typing a location in its location field, to constraints (which don't typically even modify the actual transformation numbers anyways.)